# Building a timeline from time-series CSV data

Tags: python, pandas, csv

This isn't about a specific error I am getting, more of a question of what data structures and algorithms I should use to accomplish my goal. Let me know if this would be better suited a different board like Software Engineering.

I have IoT devices which dump data into CSVs which are getting too large for humans to parse. The CSVs look something like this:

```
Time,Sensor1,State1,State2,State3,Sensor2,Sensor3,Sensor4,State4...
2019-05-04T10:04:45.601000Z,0.19,0,0,1,25.67,298.8,12.3,5...
2019-05-04T10:04:58.133000Z,0.23,0,1,2,24.53,300.1,14.4,6...
...
```

In one directory, there are maybe a dozen or two CSVs I would like to analyze as a group. Each CSV has dozens of columns and tens of thousands of rows. Each CSV's first column is Time, and within that CSV the timesteps will be uniform (although they won't be exact). With the exception of Time, the column headers in a CSV group are unique (no two CSVs share a column name, besides Time which they all have). Sometimes the timesteps will be 10 seconds, and sometimes they will be 2 seconds or even smaller intervals. Across different CSVs, the time column is likely to cover the same time span, but the intervals may not line up perfectly. For example, in the above CSV, we have a datapoint at 2019-05-04T10:04:45.601000Z. Another CSV in the same directory (group) might have the nearest timestamp at 2019-05-04T10:04:49.601000Z (four seconds later).

I want to construct a timeline of "Events" that occur by scanning the CSVs for state transitions. Not all variable changes are significant, so I want to be able to declare what state transitions I care about. I would like to use the following class:

```py
class StateTransition:
    def __init__(self, variable, from_state, to_state, name, relevant_measurements=()):
        self.variable = variable
        self.from_state = from_state
        self.to_state = to_state
        self.name = name
        self.relevant_measurements = relevant_measurements
```

I will maintain a list of instances of StateTransitions to look for, like this:

```py
states = (
    StateTransition(variable='State2',
                    from_state=0, to_state=1,
                    name='Cable plugged in',
                    relevant_measurements=('State1', 'Sensor4', )),
    StateTransition(variable='State2',
                    from_state=1, to_state=0,
                    name='Cable unplugged',
                    relevant_measurements('State1', 'Sensor3', )),
)
```

Relevant measurements refer to other variables, which may or may not come from the same CSV. The point of relevant_measurements is to know what the value of those other measurements (or states) were at the time of the state transition. Since the relevant_measurement might come from another CSV, I will have to settle for the value of that measurement at the time nearest the timestamp of the state transition. I imagine constructing an object like this:

```py
from datetime import datetime
class TimelineEvent:
    def __init__(self, state_transition: StateTransition, timestamp: datetime):
        self.st = state_transition
        self.timestamp = timestamp
        self.measurements = {}
```

Where self.measurements is a dict that, for a 'Cable plugged in' event, would look like this:

```py
{'State1': 0,
 'Sensor4': 14.4,}
```

The end goal is to create a list of TimelineEvents for a CSV group according to the StateTransitions I have defined. Once I have a list of timeline events, I can display them however I like, that part I can easily figure out. Where I struggle is how to build that list of TimelineEvents. Should I go through one CSV at a time, and sort the timeline later according to the timestamp? Should I step through all the CSVs at the same time? Should I step through the CSVs according to their timestamp? Is there a useful data structure I can load all the CSVs into which makes searching through temporally aligned data easy? I have never used pandas, but I included it in the tags because I imagine it provides tools that might be useful here, but it's certainly not required for an answer.

Memory usage is not of large concern here. As for runtime, it doesn't have to be fast but it'd be nice if it completes before the sun implodes. Worst case, assume one hundred thousand rows of CSV, 100 columns, and 50 state transitions defined.

I have contemplated storing the state transitions into a dictionary which would look like this:

```py
states_dict[variable][from_state][to_state] = {'name': 'something', relevant_measurements=('some_sensor',),}
```

^Something like the above would provide efficient lookups of StateTransitions. You may assume I've already done that if it helps.

For clarification: I don't require an implementation to accept an answer. If you can point me to the tools and/or describe an algorithm that would accomplish this in a way I can understand, I would accept such an answer.

Comment: A challenge!
For what programming language?

Comment: I would prefer Python as that will be easiest for me to maintain, integrate, and perhaps optimize in the future. But I suppose I would accept an answer in R or even a bunch of excel macros if it can do the job and I can trigger it to happen from Python.

Comment: Can you elaborate, with a example, "StateTransitions"?. For "Cable plugged in" is to look up on a CVS file if column "State1" has value "0" and "Sensor4" value "1"?

Comment: State2 represents the state of the cable. When the cable is plugged in, State2 is 1. When unplugged, State2 is 0. For a "Cable plugged in" event, I want to look down the column for State2 and see the value change from 0 to 1. Take that row when State2 first becomes 1 and get the timestamp from that row. That will be the time at which the "Cable [was] plugged in." Now find the values of State1 and Sensor4 closest to that time, and store those values in a TimelineEvent instance. If State1 and Sensor4 are in the same CSV, it'll be from the same row. Does that make sense?

Comment: It's a little confusin. How to detect column "State2" from "1" to "0"? Is there a row with value "1" and other row with value "1"? If columns "State1" and "Sensor" exist in the same CVS file are on the same row  of columna "State2" with value "0". If not then search on other CVS file?

Comment: I think you have the right idea. There will be a row where ```State2``` is 0 and the next row where ```State2``` is 1. My short example CSV in the question has this. In the row where ```State2``` is 1, ```State1``` is 0 and ```Sensor4``` is 14.4. If ```Sensor4``` were not in that CSV file, you'd have to take the timestamp of that row and find the CSV with ```Sensor4``` and find the row in that CSV with the nearest timestamp, and get the value of ```Sensor4``` from there.

Comment: Provide some more examples.

Comment: A state machine is a good way to detect invalid transitions in the data.  Given sufficient time series data from IoT devices, you will see every erroneous combination of data due to the vagaries of device firmware, connectivity, time and csvs.  Imagine a missing csv row, for example.

Comment: @RichAndrews They're really just embedded systems running a lot of bare metal software dumping data. Building a full-on state machine reflecting and tracking the embedded software state would be overkill for this application. I just want to automate the work that I am currently doing: crawling through massive CSVs, looking for a state change, taking the timestamp, looking up that time in a different CSV, repeat ad nauseam. I would like to construct a timeline of events from the CSVs and debug that way instead. If there are errors or missing data that is okay as it is no worse than before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the question is not perfectly specific, there are a variety of things one typically does with time series data coming in from IoT devices.

Resampling, combining resampled with actual, applying logic (like a state machine) and looking up values between DataFrames are common.

Here is an example of that, a sort of busy box that shows some of the above on time series data, manipulated by a datetimeindex.

```
import pandas as pd
import random as r
from pandas.compat import StringIO
print(pd.__version__)

daterange = pd.date_range('2019-01-01 11:00', '2019-01-01 13:00', periods = r.randint(10,30))
df = pd.DataFrame(index=daterange, data={'sensor_data': [r.randint(0,5) for i in range(len(daterange))]})

# the actual datapoints
actual_datapoints = df.copy()
actual_datapoints['actual'] = True

# resample e.g. visualization purposes
df = df.resample('5T').last().ffill()
# but let's not confuse these datapoints and the result of resampling with actual datapoints
df['actual'] = False
# for these false datapoints, delete the ones for which there is an actual
mask = df.index.isin(actual_datapoints.index)
df = df.drop(df[mask].index)

# combine actual datapoints with the resampled timeseries
df = pd.concat([actual_datapoints, df])
df.sort_index(inplace=True)

# a lookup dataframe, lookups by datetimeindex
data = """datetime,lookup_val
2019-01-01 11:00,100
2019-01-01 11:30,200
2019-01-01 12:00,300
"""
lookup_df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), index_col='datetime', parse_dates=True, infer_datetime_format=True)

# a really bad state machine. :-)
state=None
def statefunc(x):
    global state
    if x != state:
        state = x
        return 'edge'
    return state

df['state'] = df['sensor_data'].apply(statefunc)

# actual, resampled, and looked up values 
df = df.join(lookup_df)
print(df)
```

Mentioned below is a lookup based on approximate timestamps.  See: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html

Comment: So you're suggesting I resample all the columns to fit all the timestamps I have, collectively across all the CSVs? Or come up with some other regular timing interval? What made you choose 5-minute resampling? Is it possible to have the resampling done lazily, so that I only compute the missing samples that I need?

Comment: Hi Tom, resampling typically loses information, so don't do it unless a regular frequency is needed.  Aside from the mathematical qualities of resampling, it is super useful for looking at the distance between timestamps in a spreadsheet, or having intermediate values for charting, etc.  With variable intervals, it is really hard to see if rows are separated by seconds, minutes or hours. And you noted manual review of the CSVs.  The above answer combines the actual datapoints into the resampled ones, so you can have the choice of doing that or not.  Joins can be done on HH:MM for lookups too.

Comment: The intervals aren't really variable (or at least, they wouldn't be if you rounded to the nearest second), but they are staggered from one CSV to another. I think the merge_asof() is exactly what I was looking for, thanks! I will have to give this a try.

Comment: I guess the right answer to my question was really just "use pandas." I ended up getting what I needed by setting the time column as the index for each dataframe (one per CSV) and calling ```nearest_time = other_df.index.get_loc(time, method='nearest')``` on dataframes with different timestamps. Thanks anyway for showing me the light.